# Can an attractive magnetic force ever slow down an electron?

Tags: particle-physics

Can an attractive magnetic force ever slow down an electron? I know that electrons tend to accelerate towards the pole when place inside a cylindrical hollow magnet, but does this attraction ever cause them to lose velocity, say if they were going in the opposite direction (away from the core, towards the furthest point between the poles), or do they retain their velocity, merely, change direction and then gain more as they approach the tip of the tube

Comment: What is "attractive" magnetic force?

Comment: Totally confused question. How can something change direction and retain its velocity? Please review, and distinguish between speed and velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A magnetic force will not slow down an electron.

I'm not sure what kind of system you're thinking about-- it seems you have some kind of specific technology or device in mind. Perhaps you can provide more details?

The force $\vec{F}$ exerted by a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ on a moving charged particle is given by

$$\vec{F} = q(\vec{v}\times\vec{B}),$$

where $q$ is the amount of charge and $\vec{v}$ is the particle's velocity. The cross product $(\times)$ guarantees that the resulting force will always be perpendicular to the velocity, which means it will change only the particle's direction of travel, and not its speed.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields don't do any work because $\textbf{F} = q (\textbf{v} ~ \times \textbf{B} )$. However, this only applies for a point charge. In this case, assuming electron is a point charge, there won't be any change in electron's speed and hence magnetic field cannot slow it down.

Comment: Why only a point charge?

Answer (score 1):

No static, purely magnetic field ever causes an electron to slow down or speed up, no matter how complicated of a magnetic field it is.

The [Lorentz force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) is

$$\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E} + q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}\ \ .$$

$\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$ is always perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$, so when $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{F}$ is always perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$, so the electron's acceleration $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{F}/m_e$ is always perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$. That is, an electron's acceleration in a purely magnetic field only causes the electron's velocity to change direction, not to change in magnitude at all. Magnetic fields perform no [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)).